# Parsing function assigns proper value to array within itself but after call value is wrong

Tags: c, parsing, struct, variable-length-array

Having a problem with a 2D variable array of structs.

Trying to parse a text file and populate the array with the following function:

```
void populateTable(int x; int y; Entry table[x][y], 
                   int x, int y, char    fileName[])
{
    char currentLineStr[8192];
    int yIndex = 0;

    FILE *fileIn;
    FILE *fileOut;

    fileIn = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if(fileIn == 0)
    {
        perror("Cannot open input file\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        fgets(currentLineStr, 8192, fileIn);

        while (currentLineStr[0] == '#')
            fgets(currentLineStr, 8192, fileIn);

        TokenizeLine(currentLineStr, table, yIndex, x, y);
        yIndex++;
        while(fgets(currentLineStr, 8192, fileIn) != NULL)
        {
            TokenizeLine(currentLineStr, table, yIndex, x, y);

            yIndex++;
            //printf("%i\n",yIndex);
        }

        fclose(fileIn);
    }
    printf("%s\n", table[0][0].str);
    printf("%f\n", table[1][0].dVal);
}
```

The `printf` statements at the end of this return the values that they should. However immediately after the call of this function I do the same `printf` statements and they return the wrong information.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char stringToFind[256] = {"DWL_FaceMountTile"};
    char fileName[64] = {"rtest.txt"};
    char timeFile[64] = {"timefile.msgr"};
    int numEntries = 0;
    int x;
    int y;
    double time;
    double temp;
    int tTableXdim = 36;
    int tTableYdim = 20;

    x = NumColumns(fileName);
    y = NumRows(fileName);


    Entry eTable[x][y];
    Entry tTable[x][y];

    int idInstances[y];
    int rowQuantity[y];
    double clipLines[x][y];

    populateTable(tTable,tTableXdim,tTableYdim,timeFile);// call for above code.
    printf("%s\n", tTable[0][0].str);
    printf("%f\n", tTable[1][0].dVal);// I call these any they return wrong
```

If anyone could shine some light on this issue I'd appreciate it greatly.

Edit (was suggested that I post my `TokenizeLine` function):

```
void TokenizeLine(int x; int y; char currentLineStr[], Entry table[x][y], int yIndex, int x, int y)
{
    char *tokPtr;
    char *current;
    int xIndex = 0;

    current = currentLineStr;
    tokPtr = mystrsep(&current, "|");

    while(tokPtr != NULL)
    {
        if(IsDouble(tokPtr))
        {
            table[xIndex][yIndex].str = NULL;
            table[xIndex][yIndex].dVal = atof(tokPtr);
        }
        else
        {
            table[xIndex][yIndex].str = malloc(strlen(tokPtr) + 1);
            strcpy(table[xIndex][yIndex].str, tokPtr);
            table[xIndex][yIndex].dVal = 0;
        }

        tokPtr = mystrsep(&current, "|")
        xIndex++;
    }
}
```

As requested the `Entry` definition.

```
typedef struct Entry
{
    char *str;
    double dVal;
} Entry;
```

The output that I get within the `populateTable` function is.
    `DWL_FaceMountTile`
    `1.000000`

Which is completely correct and the correctness holds true for all the entries when accessed within `populateTable`

The below is what I get when accessing the table outside of `populateTable` after its been called.
the str values of the table all appear to be correct, however the dVal are all set to zero somehow as shown below.

```
DWL_FacMountTile
0.000000
```

Comment: What are the `;` doing in function declaration `void populateTable(int x; int y; Entry table[x][y], int x, int y, char    fileName[])`?  Not familiar with that syntax.  Is this the real code?

Comment: Updated the post with the entry definition.

Comment: Yes its part of using variable length arrays. You can use arguments within the function call itself assigning a length in this case x and y to the dimenstions of the entry table.

Comment: 1) Suggest using a test `TokenizeLine()` that only sets all the values of `table[0][yIndex] ...table[x-1][yIndex]`.  AFAIK `xIndex++;` is going out of  range or not all `table[][yIndex]` is initialized.  2) What is the "return the wrong information"? what is right?  3) maybe `yindex` goes out of range in `populateTable(()`?  Sorry just do not see the issue with the posted data and info.

Comment: You're passing the wrong dimensions for `tTable`.